Gmail inbox window isn't updating after mail deleted successfully using gmail API
My issues is updating the UI of gmail inbox window when i delete mail using Gmail delete api by google workspace add-on, and app script
i am expecting when i click on report button in google workspace add-on opened mail is delete from the inbox and Gmail inbox window update successfully ,

Refresh the Window.
